# Unable to add as keyword in Case statement in sql

Tags: mysql

I am having the following issue when using `WITH` in sql.

```
WITH ctes AS (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.UserID, a.Type, a.CreateDate
   ORDER BY COALESCE(CASE WHEN a.Type = 0 THEN a.CreateDate END AS CheckIn, 
                     CASE WHEN a.Type = 1 THEN a.CreateDate END AS CheckOut)) rn
)
```

I am unable to put the `as` keyword in the case statement. Can someone please help me ? It is stating incorrect syntax.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` logic makes no sense.  Can you add some sample data which would help explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Moreover, why do you even need to put aliases inside the `Coalesce(..)` statement ? Those aliases wont be referrable once Coalescing is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give an alias to a parameter to a function.
Remove the aliases:

```
WITH ctes AS (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.UserID, a.Type, a.CreateDate
   ORDER BY COALESCE(CASE WHEN a.Type = 0 THEN a.CreateDate END, 
                     CASE WHEN a.Type = 1 THEN a.CreateDate END))
)
```

---

I note that both both case expression return `a.CreateDate`. If this is not a typo, you can delete the call to coalesce and make just a single call to case, shortening the order by to just:

```
...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.Type in (0, 1) THEN a.CreateDate END
```